# Как работает RegEx Engine?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, парсер, лексер

Как работает RegEx Engine внутри? Это же не просто проход по строке (через while, например) и поиск нужных символов и последовательностей симовлов, так как это было бы очень медленно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Именно так и работает. И да, они медленные.

В реальности регулярки работают быстро благодаря тому, что успешно находят сов падение. Ну и отсечения заведомо неправильных вариантов никто не отменял, а оно на реальных примерах может давать существенное ускорение. Но в общем случае при остутствии совпадения на неудачно составленной или порсто сложной регулярке может потребоваться очень много (а то и по сути бесконечно при экспоненциальном алгоритме) времени на вычисление. Поэтому в некоторые языки (например в .net) встроена возможность указать таймаут на вычисление.

Например на js при регулярке `/^(a+)\1*$/` время увеличивается в 4 раза с удвоением длины строки, что подтверждает квадратичную асимптотику данной регулярки:

[image: скриншот]

Можно проверить самому, только надо смотреть в браузерной консоли, а не внутри сниппета. **При запуске браузер зависнет на несколько секунд или даже минут.**

```js
var res = [];

for (var len=0; len<18; ++len) {
  var s = "a".repeat(1<<len) + "b"
  var t = performance.now()
  var cur = s.match(/^(a+)\1*$/)
  res.push({ len: s.length, t: performance.now()-t, cur })
}

console.table(res)
```