# Проверка строк на соотвествие

Tags: javascript, java, c#, .net, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет, у меня есть задача: есть разные форматы номеров машин такси и нужно их рассортировать по регионам страны с минимальной затратой времени и памяти, другими словами нужно проверять строки, будет ли самый быстрый способ реализации этой задачи через регулярные выражения? Или, быть может, есть способ побыстрее и менее ресурсозатратный.
Уточнение:
N строк зафиксированными номерами. Длина одной строки — от 3до 20
символов, в её состав могут входить цифры, прописные и строчные буквы латинского алфавита, а также дефисы и пробелы.
Ограничение по времени 1 секунда, по памяти 256мб

Comment: `Мне нужно обработать номера машин, но я не скажу ни их количество, ни формат, ни правил обработки не покажу, ни длины, ни требований по производительности\памяти\железу\многопоточности, но я уже решил (непонятно почему), что лучше работать со строками, скажите мне лучший способ это сделать по времени и памяти` ? - сможете сами а это ответить? :)

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста, уточнил

Comment: Можно сделать через предкомпилированную регулярку, или написать свой довольно несложный конечный автомат для этого дела

Comment: что такое конечный автомат?

Comment: Формат какой у номеров? Как понять, к какому региону номер относится? Вам нужно просто расфасовать по регионам (словарь регион-номера)? У вас много похожих номеров (trie)?

Comment: Что бы вам начали предлагать решения, нужен алгоритм определения региона по номеру и примеры номеров (например что там в трёхсимвольных?). А скорость регулярок сильно зависит от их сложности (и мне кажется их скорость вас не огорчит). Конечно специальное, заточенное на конкретную проблему решение будет быстрее. Но его надо придумать и написать, а ргулярки вот они. Уж N номеров за секунду распарсите легко :-)

Comment: Вы даете какие то требования по памяти, но не говорите ничего о количестве номеров. Для 2 номеров подойдет что угодно. Для миллиарда 23 значных номеров 256 мегабайт не хватит.

Comment: я так понимаю, вы решаете какую то олимпиадную задачу, но решили не то что свои попытки нам не скидывать, но даже условие толком не сказать.

Comment: Щас доделаю регулярку и скину попытку с условием

Comment: регулярка - это чуть ли не самый медленный способ работы со строками.

Comment: @tym32167, далеко не всегда. К тому же, часто самый удобный.

Comment: @Qwertiy вы знаете время обработки строки длиной N регуляркой длиной M?

Comment: длинна строки от 3 до 20 символов написал же

Comment: @tym32167, в зависимости от регулярки. Какие-нибудь `^(abc)\1*$` - линейное относительно длины строки. `^.*a$` - тоже. А если `^((((((.*)*)*)*)*)*)*)*a$`, то сам дурак. Длина регулярки не важна, важна структура - регулярка - это почти минипрограмма, у которой тоже есть асимптотика сравнения. У меня проверка 13 мегабайт исходников регулярками занимает всего несколько секунд, причём, регулярки там в общем-то не самые простые.

Comment: @tym32167, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1042788/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy я не спец по регуляркам, но когда я проходил курс по алгоритмам, то приходилось строить конечные автоматы для разборок. Там везде сложность начиналась от N*M, то есть не было ничего линейного. Конечно, если писать запутанную регулярку, то можно сделать ещё хуже. Потому я стараюсь их не использовать.

Comment: @Kioshilol про длину строки я видел, а самих строк сколько?

Comment: @tym32167, вот тебе и квадратичная, и линейная - разница в одном плюсике: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqBiC.png.

Comment: @Qwertiy я ж сказал, при длине регулярки M. Логично, что при длине регулярки 2, общая производительность будет 2*N.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102508/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-tym32167).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Регулярка для проверки:

```
^([1-7]T[AB]X|7TEX) (?!0000)[0-9]{4}$
```